# Metrics sent via Datadog HTTP API does not get reflected in Metric Explorer

Tags: datadog

Referring to [Datadog's 'Submit metrics' API documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#submit-metrics), I've tried sending metrics with following payload using Postman:

- API: `POST` https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/series
- Request header: `DD-API-KEY` and `DD-APPLICATION-KEY` with valid values
- Request body (based on [Datadog sample](https://www.postman.com/datadog/workspace/datadog-s-public-workspace/request/7274195-8e07c48a-7769-4a51-bd64-b161c4e6dd58)):

```
{
    "series": [
        {
            "metric": "IvanPOCMetric",
            "points": [
                [
                    "${NOW}",
                    "1234.5"
                ]
            ]           
        }
    ]
}
```

The response was successful (*202 Accepted*) with following response body:

```
{
    "status": "ok"
}
```

However, when I try to search for my submitted metrics, via either ['Search metrics' API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#search-metrics) or **Datadog Metric Explorer**, I'm unable to find `IvanPOCMetric`.

Is there any issue with my request payload above? Or is there additional configuration needed to be done on Datadog portal to correctly 'register' the custom metric?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get it work! The payload need to be fixed as follow:

1. Use numeric tuple for `points` input, with timestamp and metric value pair.
2. The timestamp need to be **seconds** from Epoch, not **milliseconds**.

Comment: Hey. Can you please provide the response body which solved your problem? I am facing the same issue here.

Comment: I think you meant request body right? Refer to the request body example from my question above, just need to change the `points`'s to `"points": [[ 1635138151, 100 ]]`.